# Shell script file takes partial path from parameter file

Tags: shell, variables, unix

I have a parameter file(parameter.txt) which contain like below:

```
SASH=/home/ec2-user/installers
installer=/home/hadoop/path1
```

And My shell script(temp_pull.sh) is like below:

```
EPATH=`cat $1|grep 'SASH' -w| cut -d'='  -f2`
echo $EPATH
${EPATH}/data-integration/kitchen.sh   -file="$KJBPATH/hadoop/temp/maxtem/temp_pull.kjb"
```

When I run my temp_pull.sh like below:

```
./temp_pull.sh parameter.txt
```

`$EPATH` gives me correct path, but 3rd line of code takes only partial path.

Error code pasted below:

```
/home/ec2-user/installers-->out put of 2nd line  
/data-integration/kitchen.sh: No such file or directory**2-user/installer** -->out put of 3rd line
```

Comment: You can use the values from another file a bit more elegantly by sourcing it: `source "$1"` and then you will be able to use `$SASH` directly.

Comment: Thanks fedorqui..Could you please elaborate your answer..I am not well versed in shellscripting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to manually parse the values of the file, because it already contains data in the format variables are defined: `var=value`.

Hence, if the file is safe enough, you can [`source`](https://superuser.com/q/46139/204979) the file so that `SASH` value will be available just by saying `$SASH`.

Then, you can use the following:

```
source "$1"  # source the file given as first parameter
"$SASH"/data-integration/kitchen.sh -file="$KJBPATH/hadoop/temp/maxtem/temp_pull.kjb"
```

Comment: How to handle if I have multiple parameter in file.I have edited the question.

Comment: Then you will also have `$installer` available!

Comment: hey..I tried that ....I am getting same exact error.....It is taking partial data.

Comment: You should make sure the file `/home/ec2-user/installers/data-integration/kitchen.sh` exists.

Comment: I understand your point..But the value of SASH is not able to replace in the script.It is taking the partial field. Like this  2-user/installer .This is not the complete path..that is why it is giving error.

Comment: No, what I say is that the path of the script is generated by doing `$SASH` + `/data-integration/kitchen.sh`. Make sure if that is the proper way to do it, because the error clearly shows that this path / file does not exist.

Comment: @Aman I see you unaccepted and then accepted again. Is there anything we should improve in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is file which we were using was copied from windows to UNIX.So delimiter issue are the root cause.

By using **dos2unix paramfile.txt**  we are able to fix the isue.

command:

```
dos2unix paramfile.txt
```

This will convert all the delemeter of windows to unix format.